# How to fix this "React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency" warning?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, eslint-plugin-react-hooks

Here's my file:

```
// useFetcher.js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function useFetcher(action) {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  async function loadData() {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const actionData = await action();
      setData(actionData);
    } catch (e) {
      setError(e);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    loadData();
  }, [action]);
  return [data, loading, error];
}
```

On line 21, eslint complaints that:

```
React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'loadData'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.eslint(react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: When you set state after async function finishes you should [check if the component is mounted before you set the state](https://github.com/jmlweb/isMounted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way here would be to define your async function inside the `useEffect`:

```
export default function useFetcher(action) {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function loadData() {
      try {
        setLoading(true);
        const actionData = await action();
        setData(actionData);
      } catch (e) {
        setError(e);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    }

    loadData();
  }, [action]);
  return [data, loading, error];
}
```

More info in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies).

Comment: Interesting. I'm new to hooks, is there any documentation on this block scoping?

Comment: I highly recommend reading this post by D.Abramov: https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/

Comment: "If you’re not comfortable with deep dives, you might want to wait until these explanations appear elsewhere. Just like when React came out in 2013, it will take some time for people to recognize a different mental model and teach it."

Love the post so far!

Answer (score 0):

Add the `loadData` function to the array in your `useEffect`. This will get rid of the complaint:

```
useEffect(() => {
  loadData();
}, [action, loadData]);
```

Comment: Now it tells me `The 'loadData' function makes the dependencies of useEffect Hook (at line 21) change on every render. Move it inside the useEffect callback. Alternatively, wrap the 'loadData' definition into its own useCallback() Hook`

Comment: If I move `loadData` inside the callback of `useEffect`, the warning disappears. I'm new to hooks, Is this good practice?

Comment: A good linter will tell you that's of no use unless loadData came from a useCallback that has action as a dependency. If you use vscode with eslint plugin and an app created with latest create-react-app you would see the error.